# Extract and delete the first occurrence of the XML tag multiple times

Tags: shell-script, sed, xml

I have a XML file of little huge size. I have been provided with that and all I need to do is a extract some values
in between the XML tags. Since I don't have the `XML` parser utility available in my machines. I am looking for an alternate method.

To start with, there is a XML tag `<capacity> </capacity`> which repeats *n* number of time in the XML file and in between this XML tags there are many other different tags as well.

I have to get each occurrence of `<capacity> </capacity>` XML tag separately and then parse through that and extract the values under them.

```
<subcolumns><capacity><name>45.90</name>
<index>0</index>
<value_type>String</value_type>
<ignore_case_flag>1</ignore_case_flag>
<hidden_flag>0</hidden_flag>
<exclude_from_parse_flag>1</exclude_from_parse_flag>
</capacity>
<capacity><name>57.09</name>
<index>1</index>
<value_type>String</value_type>
<ignore_case_flag>1</ignore_case_flag>
<hidden_flag>0</hidden_flag>
<exclude_from_parse_flag>1</exclude_from_parse_flag>
</capacity>
<capacity><name>55</name>
<index>2</index>
<value_type>String</value_type>
<ignore_case_flag>1</ignore_case_flag>
<hidden_flag>0</hidden_flag>
<exclude_from_parse_flag>1</exclude_from_parse_flag>
</capacity>
</subcolumns>
```

So the logic which I thought was to find the first occurrence of a `<capacity> </capacity>` XML tag and print it to a temp file and then delete that first occurrence.

```
<capacity><name>45.90</name>
<index>0</index>
<value_type>String</value_type>
<ignore_case_flag>1</ignore_case_flag>
<hidden_flag>0</hidden_flag>
<exclude_from_parse_flag>1</exclude_from_parse_flag>
</capacity>
```

Henceforth when this is done for the second time the new pair of `<capacity> </capacity>` XML tag is taken into consideration.
So this has to repeat for multiple times until the last `<capacity> </capacity>` tag is found. And each time this part is extracted the data will be changing and that can be extracted.

Now all I want is to select the first occurrence of `<capacity> </capacity>` XML tag from the master XML file & print it to temp file and delete that part.

And this is what I tried and nothing worked for me.

```
sed -n '2,${/<capacity>\(.*\)<\/capacity>/\1/p;q;}' "<input XML file>" >> temp.txt
```

My further idea is to take that temp file for processing and extract the values which I need to under the `capacity` tags. For which I have already written the logic and it is working fine.

Comment: Will `<capacity>` and `</capacity>` always be on separate lines or can they appear on the same line? Can you have nested tags? I mean one `<capacity> </capacity>` inside another `<capacity> </capacity>`? Is there any specific reason why you are doing it this way instead of using an XML parser?

Comment: This is easy to do in a single pass with an `xml` parser.  However, it isn't possible to answer your question in that context, since you didn't disclose what data you want to extract and in what format.

Comment: @terdon a. <capacity> and </capacity>are always separate.
b.Nope even nested tags are present in my XML file.
c. The machine which I am using nor where I will be deploying this script once done does not have XML Parser. And I don't have the privilege to install this package as well.

Comment: @SatoKatsura
a.As commented above for some reason I don't have the XML parser available in my machine.
b. I need to extract the values of the tag name,index and hidden_value for now . And the reason for not disclosing that is I have the code already done for this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using XML parsers is the right way for manipulating XML documents.

[***xmlstarlet***](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/xmlstarlet-ug.html) solution:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -c '//capacity[1]' -n yourxml > temp.txt 
&& xmlstarlet ed -d '//capacity[1]' yourxml > tmp.xml && mv tmp.xml yourxml
```

---

```
cat temp.txt
<capacity><name>45.90</name>
<index>0</index>
<value_type>String</value_type>
<ignore_case_flag>1</ignore_case_flag>
<hidden_flag>0</hidden_flag>
<exclude_from_parse_flag>1</exclude_from_parse_flag>
</capacity>
```

---

- `xmlstarlet sel -t -c '//capacity[1]' -n yourxml > temp.txt` - extracts the first `capacity` tag declaration and redirects the output to `temp.txt`
- `xmlstarlet ed -d '//capacity[1]' yourxml > tmp.xml` - deletes the first `capacity` tag from the document (via `-d` delete action) and redirects the modified document content to temporary file `tmp.xml`
- `mv tmp.xml yourxml` - replace the initial xml document with its modified version

Comment: Thanks for the your idea!.

I was able to somehow get a server with admin privileges and installed the xmlstarlet utility.

Now to make this more stronger I made a if loop such that all the `<capacity>` blocks are captured one by one.

Now the problem when I use the $i variable along the xmlstarlet command it is printing the entire file rather than
for occurrence.

Please find the below snippet.

`#!/bin/bash`
`set -x`
`capacity_count=`grep -c "<capacity>" sample1.xml`
`for ((i=1;i<=$capacity_count;i++));`
`do
      xmlstarlet sel -t -c '//capacity["$i"]' -n sample1.xml
done`

Comment: No able to get the formatting in order to paste the code.

Answer (score 2):

Since you don't have an xml parser , give a try to this one with gnu awk:

```
$ awk -v RS="<subcolumns>|</capacity>" 'NR==2{gsub(/^\n/,"");print $0 RT;exit}' file.xml
<capacity><name>45.90</name>
<index>0</index>
<value_type>String</value_type>
<ignore_case_flag>1</ignore_case_flag>
<hidden_flag>0</hidden_flag>
<exclude_from_parse_flag>1</exclude_from_parse_flag>
</capacity>
```

Why this works:
in awk you can set a custom record / line separator. In our example we use either `<subcolumns>` or `</capacity>`

As a result with a customized record separator we can achieve this format:

```
$ awk -v RS="<subcolumns>|</capacity>" '{gsub(/^\n/,"");print NR,$0 RT}' file.xml
1 <subcolumns>
2 <capacity><name>45.90</name>
<index>0</index>
<value_type>String</value_type>
<ignore_case_flag>1</ignore_case_flag>
<hidden_flag>0</hidden_flag>
<exclude_from_parse_flag>1</exclude_from_parse_flag>
</capacity>
3 <capacity><name>57.09</name>
<index>1</index>
<value_type>String</value_type>
<ignore_case_flag>1</ignore_case_flag>
<hidden_flag>0</hidden_flag>
<exclude_from_parse_flag>1</exclude_from_parse_flag>
</capacity>
4 <capacity><name>55</name>
<index>2</index>
<value_type>String</value_type>
<ignore_case_flag>1</ignore_case_flag>
<hidden_flag>0</hidden_flag>
<exclude_from_parse_flag>1</exclude_from_parse_flag>
</capacity>
5 </subcolumns>
```

PS: NR = Number or Record/Line. RT=Record Separator used.

Accordingly you can print any `<capacity></capacity>` block by adjusting the NR number:

```
$ awk -v RS="<subcolumns>|</capacity>" 'NR==4{gsub(/^\n/,"");print $0 RT}'
<capacity><name>55</name>
<index>2</index>
<value_type>String</value_type>
<ignore_case_flag>1</ignore_case_flag>
<hidden_flag>0</hidden_flag>
<exclude_from_parse_flag>1</exclude_from_parse_flag>
</capacity>
```

Accordingly, if you need to skip a `<capacity>` section (i.e first capacity section) you can just do :

```
$ awk -v RS="<subcolumns>|</capacity>" '{gsub(/^\n/,"")}NR!=2{print $0 RT}'
<subcolumns>
<capacity><name>57.09</name>
<index>1</index>
<value_type>String</value_type>
<ignore_case_flag>1</ignore_case_flag>
<hidden_flag>0</hidden_flag>
<exclude_from_parse_flag>1</exclude_from_parse_flag>
</capacity>
<capacity><name>55</name>
<index>2</index>
<value_type>String</value_type>
<ignore_case_flag>1</ignore_case_flag>
<hidden_flag>0</hidden_flag>
<exclude_from_parse_flag>1</exclude_from_parse_flag>
</capacity>
</subcolumns>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
chunk=2; # specify the tag chunk number here which must be > 0
perl -l -0777ne "print((m{(<capacity>.*?</capacity>)}sg)[${chunk:-1}-1])" yourxmlfile
```

---

### Results

```
<capacity><name>57.09</name>
<index>1</index>
<value_type>String</value_type>
<ignore_case_flag>1</ignore_case_flag>
<hidden_flag>0</hidden_flag>
<exclude_from_parse_flag>1</exclude_from_parse_flag>
</capacity>
```